# KeyError: "['something' 'something'] not in index"

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently encountering this error:

> KeyError: "['Malaysia' 'Singapore'] not in index"

with the error pointing at :

> ---> 37         wide_data = wide_data[['Malaysia','Singapore']]

Upon checking **wide_data** with `print(wide_data.columns)` it returns :

```
MultiIndex([( 'total_cases',  'Malaysia'),
            ( 'total_cases', 'Singapore'),
            (   'new_cases',  'Malaysia'),
            (   'new_cases', 'Singapore'),
            ('total_deaths',  'Malaysia'),
            ('total_deaths', 'Singapore'),
            (  'new_deaths',  'Malaysia'),
            (  'new_deaths', 'Singapore')],
           names=[None, 'location'])
```

Both does exist. I'm not sure where did my code goes wrong.

Below are my code snippet and [Dataset](https://ourworldindata.org/coronavirus-source-data) used:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv('covid-data-2020.csv', index_col='date', parse_dates=True)
data = df[df.location.isin(['Malaysia', 'Singapore'])]

wide_data = data.pivot(columns='location', values=list(data.columns[2:6]))
wide_data = wide_data[['Malaysia','Singapore']]
wide_data.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
fig = px.line(wide_data.melt(id_vars='date'), x='date', y='value', color='location')
fig.update_yaxes(title='Malaysia vs Singapore')
fig.show()
```

Comment: If that `covid-data-2020.csv` is available somewhere, you should put the URL so it is easier for everyone to try the code and suggest a solution.

Comment: @FxIII added hyperlink for that. thank you for reminding

Comment: Is this the link to your csv file?
https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.csv

Comment: yes thats the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to compare the growth of the total cases/deaths in Malaysia and Singapore?
If so, maybe instead of :

```
wide_data = wide_data[['Malaysia','Singapore']]
```

You use:

```
wide_data = wide_data[['total_cases']]
```

Which will produce the graph you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to swap columns' multiIndex like that:

```
wide_data.columns = wide_data.columns.swaplevel(0,1)
```

before doing

```
wide_data = wide_data[['Malaysia','Singapore']]
```